# What are the 2022 Nobel Prize winning papers of Alain Aspect, John Clauser, and Anton Zeilinger, and how do they fit into the timeline of QIS?

Tags: teleportation, bell-experiment, foundations, history

The 2022 Nobel Prize in Physics was [awarded to](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2022/press-release/) Alain Aspect, John Clauser, and Anton Zeilinger for "experiments with entangled photons... pioneering quantum information science".

Presumably there were noteworthy publications of each.

> **Are there separate publications at least partially authored by each of the three, that can each be said to be a "Nobel-prize winning paper"?**

The Nobel prizes have historically been awarded for theorists whose work is later experimentally validated; some more recent Nobel prizes have somewhat loosened that theory vs. experiment dichotomy.

Can we create a timeline, with links to papers, from EPR to Bell to CHSH to the 70s - early 80's work of experiments of Clauser and Aspect to the GHZ/teleportation experiments and the Delft experiments, identifying noteworthy [gedanken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment)- and actual experiments, and how they anticipated or led into each other?

Comment: You can find the scientific report from the Nobel prize committee [here](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2022/10/advanced-physicsprize2022.pdf). Which cites the works by the various authors that led to their prize.

Comment: [Useful link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.04737.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Well, a sidebar in [Quanta magazine's](https://www.quantamagazine.org/pioneering-quantum-physicists-win-nobel-prize-in-physics-20221004/) article had already created a nice timeline on the experiments and events leading up to the 2022 Nobel Prize in physics.

Also as identified by @Rammus in a comment, the Nobel Prize committee has provided a very readable [summary](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2022/10/advanced-physicsprize2022.pdf) of the work, and how they led and lead from one idea to another.

We may have at least the following landmark papers:

- **1935 theoretical physics:** The foundational Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen gedanken-experiment is introduced in "[Can Quantum-Mechanical Description of Physical Reality Be Considered Complete?](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777)"
- **1964 theoretical  physics:** Bell introduces his though-experiment "[On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen paradox](https://journals.aps.org/ppf/abstract/10.1103/PhysicsPhysiqueFizika.1.195)"
- **1969 theoretical  physics:** Clauser, Horne, Shimony, and Holt provide a (simpler?) version of the Bell experiment "[Proposed Experiment to Test Local Hidden-Variable Theories](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.880)"
- **1972 experimental physics:** Clauser and Freedman helped reduce these ideas to practice in "[Experimental Test of Local Hidden-Variable Theories](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.28.938)" in 1972
- **Early 80's experimental physics:** The additional experimental work of the early 80's led by Aspect, Grangier, and Roger closed some loopholes in the CF72 work, including ["Experimental Tests of Realistic Local Theories via Bell's Theorem"](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.460)
- **1989 theoretical physics:** Greenberger, Horne, and Zeilinger's gedanken-experiment paper "[Going Beyond Bell's Theorem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0849-4_10)" improve on the EPR experiment by studying the [GHZ state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state)
- **1993 theoretical physics:** Entanglement as a resource is studied in "[Teleporting an Unknown Quantum State via Dual Classical and Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Channels](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.70.1895)" by Bennett, Brassard, Crépeau, Jozsa, Peres, and Wootters
- **1999 experimental physics:** The experimental realization of such GHZ-states in "[Observation of Three-Photon Greenberger-Horne-Zeilinger Entanglement](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.1345)" led by Bouwmeester, Pan, Daniell, Weinfurter, and Zeilinger

There are many other papers and studies in-between these seminal works - for example, EPR spoke of continuous position/momentum entanglement, but Bohm conceptually modified this to thinking about discrete qubits.  Also, these physics thought- and actual-experiments explored the nature of [entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) and its importance to  [quantum foundations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_foundations), but did not yet appear to consider much in the way of *algorithmic* or *computational* aspects of quantum mechanics, and the power afforded therein.

---

<sup>Such a laundry list of names, dates, and papers is perhaps of some value, although clearly there are and may always be representation issues, e.g., from the metes and bounds of the Nobel's famous lists of requirements for physics.  For example only up to three prizes are awarded each year, and only for living candidates.</sup>